# Threadsafe observer pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, windows-phone-8.1

I'm writing an application for WPF in MVC pattern. The purpose of application is to display some data in the database and these data are being updated asynchronously.

I'm thinking about how to design the architecture, such that it will be thread-safe. In particular:

- Each page (or its viewmodel) must be able to subscribe and unsubscribe from the service, which updates the database.
- The service updating the database informs all  subscribers, that new data arrived and that they should refresh their views.

Obviously, the page, which is just being closed should unsubscribe from the service and the page, which just appears, should (or may) subscribe.

I could put subscription inside a critical section, as well as broadcast about new data, but then imagine the following scenario (page ~= its viewmodel, that does not matter much here):

- Service enters critical section to broadcast information about new data (in separate thread)
- Page tries to enter critical section to unsubscribe (in main thread)
- Service informs page about new data (in separate thread).
- Page populates its fields and raises PropertyChange event (in separate thread).
- PropertyChange event is marshalled to the main thread. Which waits for the critical section.

And it looks like a deadlock to me.

How can I safely design this architecture to avoid such deadlocks? Maybe pages should never unsubscribe? Or is there another way to secure threads such that they won't deadlock?

Comment: This looks really weird as an approach. Specifically, how does the 'service' know that some data is new? is it because it has just been submitted by your own app?

Comment: Why does the main thread needs to acquire critical section? (in last bullet point)? Also why are you firing events while holding locks?, that's very likely to cause deadlocks! Also some code demonstrating the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Generally speaking you can not have deadlock with _one_ resource. To have deadlock you must have 2 or more guarded resources, and a closed cycle in the blocking -> blocked graph. You use the 'critical section' term (which is not a problem) but you must clearify what guard/mutex/semaphor/etc do you use, do you have 2 or more or just only one. My guess, that after the unsubscribe code part run (in the main UI thread) the marshalled (queued) PropertyChange will run with no deadlock. Of course this can cause problems if data structures are invalid, however this has nothing to do with the deadlock.

Comment: @zaitsman: The service can not know, that's why it is _polling_ (I suppose). Spook's architecture servers to _hide_ this polling ugliness (which is coming from the DB circumstances), and transform the polling to event driven approach.

Comment: @g.pickardou that's how you read it, and how i read it initially, too. But i want the confirmation from OP on that point. The answer to that will help determine the correct approach.

Comment: @zaitsman It checks periodically (or on request) a few Internet sources. But all network connections are done asynchronously, so it doesn't know, when the processing is finished (other than subscribing to the checking service - or similar method). Also, user may start checking and then immediately close the page, in which case the resulting information should be dismissed.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The critical section is being held, because the page tries to unsubscribe (point 2). However, on second thought, that shouldn't block, because unsubscribing is a process, which does not wait for anything. I have no code to demonstrate, because I'm still thinking on how to write it :)

Comment: Without code I can't suggest a good answer. All I can say is don't take a lock and raise event or call any virtual methods. It's not something new, it is generally discouraged. So, redesign your architecture so that you don't need a lock while raising an event. Take a lock before or after the event, but not when raising it. Or handle the observer asynchronously.

Comment: @g.pickardou: "To have deadlock you must have 2 or more guarded resources" -- but there are 2 guarded resources. The explicit lock for the collection, and the implicit lock for the UI thread. This is a common mistake when dealing with the thread affinity issues of Winforms, WPF, and the like, to forget that the UI thread itself is a synchronized resource, and can participate in a deadlock just like any other. So the OP is right to be concerned about code that takes the lock in the UI thread, but which also might have to wait on the UI thread while holding the lock.

Comment: Until you post some code that has a genuine deadlock risk, it's not really possible to provide a good, specific answer on how to avoid that risk. That said, I will note that the standard idiom for raising events in .NET -- to copy the event field to a local variable before checking it for null and invoking it -- allows for lock-free event-raising. It does introduce the possibility of a race, wherein an object subscribed to the event receives the event after it thought it had unsubscribed, and you'll have to be careful to handle that correctly (if necessary...it often requires nothing special).

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating it a lot. Is there really a problem if you handle the event once after (at the same time) you've unsubscribed from it? If so, how about you remove all locks and just add a `bool isUnloaded` to the page(s) and set it to true when you unsubscribe from the event and then just check that bool in the event handler and ignore it if the bool is `true`?

Comment: @Peter Duniho: There is no "lock" on the UI thread. Some actions, like binding, UI intecactions, and explicit marshalled 'Invoke's are _serialized_ to be executed in the context of UI thread. but this is not the same as a resource guarded by a mutex or semaphore. Of course we do not know about how this serialization is implemented, and hidden resources like queues may or _may_not_ be locked. (Note there are lock free queue implementatins).

Comment: @g.pickardou: "this is not the same as a resource guarded by a mutex or semaphore" -- in terms of deadlock, _of course it is_. It's _exactly_ the same. Only one operation can occur on the UI thread at a time, and until that operation finishes, no other operation can begin (never mind complete). The UI thread is a synchronized resource just like any other, and if some other thread is holding a lock and waiting for the UI thread while the UI thread is waiting for the lock, you get deadlock.

Comment: @Peter Duniho: "if some other thread is holding a lock and waiting for the UI thread". That's the point. I mean _if_. In the sample no  other thread waits for the UI thread. Marshalling a call via Invoke does not mean mandatory waiting. I normal case it is an async operation placing a message to a queue.

Comment: @g.pickardou: first, "Marshalling a call via Invoke does not mean mandatory waiting" -- _of course it does_. The `Control.Invoke()` method is synchronous and will not return until the operation has completed on the UI thread. Second, this whole thread of conversation is not about the specific sample, but your comment that "To have deadlock you must have 2 or more guarded resources", and my point that that particular prerequisite is satisfied here, because the UI thread is inherently a "guarded resource".

Comment: @Peter Duniho: My bad: Replace Invoke() with BeginInvoke() or _anything_ async what you want. Not that was the point. Regarding a thread as "a resource to wait" makes harder to understand the problem domain. Of course in a higher abstraction level a _thread_ always waits to an other _thread_, but in lower level _(implementation)_ there are only different kind of guarded resources nothing else. The guards can provided by the OS or the CPU depending the type or level. My point was: If the implementation is using _one_ resource and guard in both thread, there is no chance to have deadlock.

Comment: @g.pickardou: "If the implementation is using one resource and guard in both thread, there is no chance to have deadlock" -- but as I've already explained, that's just not true. It is possible to avoid deadlock (e.g. by using the asynchronous `BeginInvoke()` instead, or simply by not holding a lock while calling `Invoke()`), but it's false to claim that it cannot happen. It is trivial to cause deadlock in that scenario, and it's a common mistake to make for programmers inexperienced with that area of programming.

Comment: @Peter Duniho: Clearly you are right. This case satisfies the two resource scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the post is tagged WPF and WP-8.1 and the clarification in the comments, i would do the following:

1. Have the base Model class (the one with properties holding relevant data) implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`
2. Have the Model for ALL pages as `ObservableCollection<BaseModel>`. The model should also implement a mutex/lock property instantiated in the constructor.
3. Share the model across all viewmodels (e.g. share the instance of the model).
4. In the 'Service' performing async operation, i would only `lock` the section of the code that would `Add` or `Remove` items from the Model ObservableCollection using the lock object from the Model itself. This section MUST be placed in the `Dispatcher.Invoke()` or equivalent platform call. This ensures that it is only UI thread that is waiting to update the collection.
5. I would bind all the UI in the relevant pages to the model reference in the viewmodel.

This way the UI and viewmodels are careless to the specific service events thus eliminating the overhead of subscribing, and you also limit the duplication of the data if you share the model - even with 20 pages on screen, your service will perform a single update that is propagated to the UI and viewmodels by the powers of the framework (binding).

Comment: (Not evaluating the whole answer just pointing on a mistake)
If the Add / Remove operations are placed in Dispatcher.Invoke() then there is no need to lock: All access to the ObservableCollection serialized to the UI thread consequently no concurrency issues and race condition occur on _that_ resource.

Comment: @g.pickardou i considered that, and you are right. But this will ensure that no other cpde would be able to modify the collection (e.g. in case this is but a part of the application). And if it is just one thread, the lock, while misleading, will be a minimal overhead.

Comment: "this will ensure that no other code would be able modify". The lock does not ensure this. Any (erratic) code can still modify the collection, simply not using the same guard or not marshalling the modifying operation to the UI thread. The lock itself does lock _nothing_. Like the red light in traffic, drivers who honor it are "synhronized", others may cause accident. So doing both locking _and_ serializing is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be: Do not do the unsubscribe operation in the UI thread. (In general do not block the UI thread.) Do it in async way, fire and forget.

Alternatively you may take a look to [Rx (Reactive Extensions)](https://rx.codeplex.com/) what are exactly for this purpose: Implementing the observer pattern in multithreaded way.

---

Silently "just not unsubscribe" is probably not a good idea. Although I do not know your implementation details, if the event handlers are instance methods, then a reference to that instance implicitly will be kept by the service, and depending the reference chain maybe your page or other instances will be prevented to garbage collected.

---

"Or is there another way to secure threads such that they won't deadlock?" Currently in .NET framework there is no magic trick what automatically prevents deadlock. Other multithreaded environments may or may not provide an automatic deadlock *resolution* (note: not prevention) service what can detect a deadlock (after it happen) and automatically choose a victim. In .NET it could be an exception what occurs *while* your are waiting to a resource. (again this is not implemented yet)